# Multi windows range calculations data.table vs dplyr

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I'm doing range calculations (i.e. max and min) over multiple windows on stocks returns. 
I have my version in dplyr, but many people publishing benchmarking where calculations with data.table are much faster. I've created the version with data.table syntax, however it's slower than dplyr one.
Could anyone help me to find better way to use data.table to make it faster?
Many thanks.

```
library(Quandl)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

tickers <- c("GOOG/NASDAQ_AAPL", "GOOG/NASDAQ_MSFT", 
             "GOOG/NYSE_IBM", "GOOG/NASDAQ_GOOG") 

data <- Quandl(tickers,transformation = "rdiff")

returns <- gather(data, stock, value, -Date) %>%
    separate(stock, c("name", "field"), " - ") %>%
    filter(
       field == "Close"
    ) %>%
    select(
       - field
    )

returns_dt <- data.table(returns)

multi_window_range <- function(data) {
    result_1y <- data %>%
        filter(
            Date >= Sys.Date() - 365
        ) %>% 
        group_by(name) %>%
        summarise(
            max_1y = max(value, na.rm = TRUE),
            min_1y = min(value, na.rm = TRUE)
        )
    result_2y <- data %>%
        filter(
            Date >= Sys.Date() - 365 * 2
        ) %>%
        group_by(name) %>%
        summarise(
            max_2y = max(value, na.rm = TRUE),
           min_2y = min(value, na.rm = TRUE)
       )
    result_5y <- data %>%
        filter(
            Date >= Sys.Date() - 365 * 5
        ) %>%
        group_by(name) %>%
        summarise(
            max_5y = max(value, na.rm = TRUE),
            min_5y = min(value, na.rm = TRUE)
        )
    return(inner_join(inner_join(result_1y, result_2y, by = "name"), result_5y, by = "name"))
}

multi_window_range_dt <- function(data) {
    setkey(data, name)
    result_1y <- data[Date >= Sys.Date() - 365,
                      list(
                        max_1y = max(value, na.rm = TRUE),
                        min_1y = min(value, na.rm = TRUE)
                      ), by = "name"]
   result_2y <- data[Date >= Sys.Date() - 365 * 2,
                     list(
                        max_2y = max(value, na.rm = TRUE),
                        min_2y = min(value, na.rm = TRUE)
                     ), by = "name"]
   result_5y <- data[Date >= Sys.Date() - 365 * 5,
                     list(
                        max_5y = max(value, na.rm = TRUE),
                        min_5y = min(value, na.rm = TRUE)
                     ), by = "name"]
   return(result_1y[result_2y][result_5y])
}

microbenchmark(
    multi_window_range(returns),
    multi_window_range_dt(returns_dt)
)


Unit: milliseconds
                              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
       multi_window_range(returns) 6.341532 6.522303 6.915266 6.692666 6.922623 10.16709   100
 multi_window_range_dt(returns_dt) 7.537073 7.738516 8.066579 7.865968 8.073114 12.68021   100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
multi_window_range_dt2 <- function(data) {
       data[, {
        rng1 <- range(value[Date > Sys.Date() - 365], na.rm = TRUE)
        rng2 <- range(value[Date > Sys.Date() - 2*365], na.rm = TRUE)
        rng5 <- range(value[Date > Sys.Date() - 5*365], na.rm = TRUE)
        list(max_1y = rng1[2], min_1y = rng1[1],
             max_2y = rng2[2], min_2y = rng2[1],
             max_5y = rng5[2], min_5y = rng5[1])
       }, by = "name"]
}

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(multi_window_range(returns), multi_window_range_dt2(returns_dt))[1:4]
```

which gives this on my laptop:

```
                                test  replications elapsed relative
1        multi_window_range(returns)           100    2.39    1.189
2 multi_window_range_dt2(returns_dt)           100    2.01    1.000
```

This indicates that `multi_window_range` takes 18.9% more time than `multi_window_range_dt2`:

Comment: It looks like the main advantage here comes from using range rather then min and max separately. Anyway, this is a good idea.

Comment: It may be due to the elimination of the joins at the end, as well.

Comment: Ah, yes, the saving comes from splitting `by="name"` only once vs. thrice in the question. The fair comparison would be with `dplyr` grouping only once as well.

Comment: Yes, if the purpose were to compare dplyr and data.table its not a fair comparison since we could apply these ideas to dplyr too but the question as stated was how to speed up the data.table code.

Comment: Actually, use the same trick in dplyr not very easy. `summarise` doesn't accept `range`, while do is not very fast.

Comment: Yes, but you could get part way there like this: ` data %>%
filter(Date > Sys.Date() - 5*365, !is.na(value)) %>%             group_by(name) %>% summarize(max_1y = max(value[Date > Sys.Date() - 365]), min_1y = min(value[Date > Sys.Date() - 365]), max_2y = max(value[Date > Sys.Date() - 2*365]), min_2y = min(value[Date > Sys.Date() - 2*365]), max_5y = max(value), min_5y = min(value))`